# SetEnvIf - Match all sub-domaines except two

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I would like to set an ENV variable based on hostnames.
I used regex to match all sub-domaines except "toto" and "tata", I tried several possibilities, but none of them works...

```
SetEnvIf Host ^prefix-(.*?!(toto|tata))-env\.example\.net$ IS_FORBIDDEN
SetEnvIf Host ^prefix-(?!toto|tata)-env\.example\.net$ IS_FORBIDDEN
SetEnvIf Host ^prefix-!(toto|k-tata)(\w+)-env\.example\.net$ IS_FORBIDDEN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
SetEnvIf Host ^((?!(toto|tata).+)\.example\.net)$ IS_FORBIDDEN
```

To match against host header in both upper and lower cases, you could use `SetEnvIfNoCase`

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^((?!(toto|tata).+)\.example\.net)$ IS_FORBIDDEN
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't worked either, appreciate your tip though :-).
I tried this as well:

`SetEnvIf Host ^prefix-((?!(toto|ta-ta).+)-env\.example\.net)$ IS_FORBIDDEN`